# Adding CSS rule to some elements

Tags: html, css

I have css rule that goes like this

```
div#tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstrip-4.k-content.k-state-active{
    background-image: url("http://wwww.example.com/logo2.png") !important;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is with #tabstrip-4 i dont know how any numbers it will be and i want to apply that role to all that elements, only id of elements will be changed like 2 3 4 5 etc..

Any pseuso selector solution?

Comment: UM, that is what classes are for.

Comment: Can `x` be any number where `#tabstrip-x` ?

Answer (score 3):

That's what classes are for. Put classes on just elements you want to style that way and add your CSS for the class. If this is, for some reason, not viable, you can always use the "starts-with" selector in CSS:

```
div[id^="tabstrip-"] {
   /* Your CSS*/
}
```

Comment: It depends on the browser you need to support [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/YLqqN/) for me and should in anything [above IE6](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "starts with" selector: `div[id^='tabstrip-']`

```
div#tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div[id^='tabstrip-'].k-content.k-state-active{
    background-image: url("http://wwww.example.com/logo2.png") !important;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```